# filter dataframe based on a given value

Tags: r, dataframe

empdata is a dataframe as given below:

```
employee <- c('John','Peter','Jolie')
salary    <- c(10000, 20000, 30000)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-25','2011-10-14'))
empdata <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
```

I want to extract the total number of rows in empdata where the date is between [startdate] and [enddate]. For example, if the startdate = 2010-11-1 and enddate = 2010-11-30, then i want answer = 2.

Comment: Using `data.table` (if the answers provided below are what you are looking for); `setDT(empdata)[between(startdate, startDate,endDate), .N]`

Comment: Based on the data you provided, I got the result as `2`. `setDT(empdata)[between(startdate, startDate,endDate), .N]#
[1] 2` given that the `startDate` and `endDate` are also date class

Comment: I don't know the problem on your side.  I am using the devel version of data.table.

Comment: I think either one of the three solutions below should work, not tested though (and replace the quoted strings with the actual date object)

Comment: **please do not erase your question**.

Comment: @user6633625673888 if you think the answer is relevant, please upvote and accept it

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help you

```
NROW(empdata[(empdata$startdate >= "startdate" & empdata$startdate <= "enddate"),])
```

This would give you the number of rows in the filtered data frame.

Comment: Wouldn't it return 1? Shoudn't it  to be `>=` (if the desired answer is 2 as stated by the OP)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
mystartdate = '2010-11-01'
mystopdate = '2010-11-30'

empdata[empdata$startdate > mystartdate & empdata$startdate < mystopdate,]
```

Comment: I don't think the will work with a character representation of start/enddate

Comment: Run POSIXt over the date

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant. Regarding your comment, `>` method dispatching will handle that part. Never mind.

Comment: I did... When u put the condition, where i have used date as string. Use it as cast typed into POSIXt

Comment: This should be `mystartdate = '2010-11-01' ; mystopdate = '2010-11-30'` and then they should be represented as `mystartdate` instead of `"mystartdate"`. As `"mystartdate"` is just a string rather a stored variable.

Comment: No. See my edit. `as.Date` isn't needed as `>` does a methods dispatch. and there is no such thing as `"mystartdate"`.

Comment: You want number of rows? Or actual filtered rows?

Comment: I'm not the OP. I don't know what he wants. Either way, you can add `nrow` here

Comment: M so sorry. I thought u were the OP. My bad

Answer (score 1):

The package [`dplyr`](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) does such things easily and efficiently (nice for larger data sets).
Here :

```
library(dplyr)
mystartdate = '2010-11-1'
mystopdate = '2010-11-30'
# First filter you dataframe, then count the number of rows
nrow(filter(empdata, startdate >= mystartdate & startdate <= mystopdate))
```

Note: I suppose from your post that it should include the date mentioned (since the desired answer is 2). Make sure to check the operators following your needs.